# How to get the WNCK window that a known GDK Window belongs to?

Tags: gtk3, gdk, wnck

I'd like to know some process info of a window that WNCK could provide. But I do not know the WNCK window, instead, I have a GDK window at hand, which may be a sub part of the WNCK window.

How could I get to the WNCK window from the GDK window?